# Create Robots.txt for all virtual hosts on Wamp and Windows

Tags: apache, wamp

I am looking to create a way by which all my localhost website are not accessible by search engine robots. Adding robots.txt to each virtual host is one option but I am looking for a way to do this for all previous and new virtual as you may know Wamp allow creation of virtual host through GUI so it would be good to add a way so that all new virtual host automatically refer to a robots.txt file so they are not being tracked

Comment: Unless you changed the access in Apache. Nothing from outside your PC can access your sites in WAMPServer, Virutally Hosted or not :)

Comment: Sorry this is fresh wamp installation , havent changed anything. Almost all of the website I download have Analytics/tracking code added and I am now identifying they are being shown over tracking dashboards

Comment: Do you actually want your sites to be visible from the internet?

Comment: If this is Google analytics calls made from javascript on your web pages, then the `robots.txt` is not going to stop that from happening. `robots.txt` only applies to search engines searching your site. And even then it is not enforcable, they can ignore it if they are ___bad robots___ :)

Comment: In the past I have had to wrap the GA js code in a test in PHP, so that it only gets put into the page if the code is running on the live site

Comment: Yeah the code that get called is Google analytics tracking code which is javascript based mostly all of the search engines have a js based tracking code only so I thought there must be a way to stop this from happening

Comment: Alternatively, I seem to remember Google allow you to setup a "Please Ignore" if calls are made from specific IP addresses. Thats mainly used to stop inhouse dev/testers affecting the stats, but you could use that to stop calls from your IP address from being logged

Answer (score -2):

just change the alias for robots.txt inside your host configuration and point it to the same file.

Comment: hey there.. maybe have a look at [answer] to get better feedback next time